# Are there overall limits to de minimis safe harbor expenses?

Tags: united-states, taxes, rental-property, california

I have a short term rental property in California, USA.

In 2023 I made multiple independent updates such as new appliances, entertainment equipment, furniture.

Each of these are individually invoiced at less than $2000 but since there are many of them they add up to around $15k.

Is there an overall limit to what can be included, in summation, to de minimis expenses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no "overall" limit. The [26 CFR 1.263(a)-1(f)(ii)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/26/1.263(a)-1) talks about cost limit *per line item* or *per invoice*. The CFR limit is $500 per such, but it was modified by the IRS ([notice 2015-82](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-drop/n-15-82.pdf)) to $2500 per such starting the year 2016. More details [here](https://www.irs.gov/businesses/small-businesses-self-employed/tangible-property-final-regulations).